# Create Product Programatically with different attribute sets

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attribute-set

> Current Feature

Once we Click on Custom button "**Button1**"  present in **Original** Product view page [ This original product is created with **Attribute set id 1** ] , We are creating **new** Product Programatically with **attribute set id = 2.**

> What i need

suppose if that original product is created with **Attribute set id 3** , Than I want to create **new** Product Programatically with **attribute set id = 4.**

```
public function saveProduct($type, $doSave = true, $originalProduct) 
{
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product->setTypeId($type)
        ->setAttributeSetId(2);

    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: How'd your products being inported into website? Is it via CSV or other else?

Comment: @PYYick we use magmi [ csv ] and sometimes manually also we upload.... but here we are creating programtically......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested this as standalone script, but it should also work in your controller code.

***Note:*** this a very basic code ... product data is just copied, stock data and websites isn't set here. This has to be added in your code!

```
// get current product example
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$setId = $product->getAttributeSetId();

// attribute set mapping
// current ID => new ID
$attributSets = array(
    1 => 2,
    3 => 4,
);

if (in_array($setId, array_keys($attributSets))) {
    $new = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $new->setData($product->getData()); // copy data from original product
    $new->setId(null); // reset ID
    $new->setSku($product->getSku() .  '_NEW' );
    $new->setAttributeSetId($attributSets[$setId]);
    $new->save();
}
```

Comment: I updated your code as here : https://pastebin.com/kDHn1M62 , seems i am missing somewhere, can you please check once.....

Comment: Would be helpful to describe whats going wrong ;) This seems wrong to me: `$setId = $product->getAttributeSetId();` Replace it witth `$setId = $originalProduct->getAttributeSetId();`

Comment: This is peRFect , Thanks a lot for your valuable time.....

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple to set different attribute set for different roducts in ONE CSV file. On the column `attribute_set_code` of the product CSV, just indicate the attribute set you want to have. Then enter the value of the product attributes, and you're done!

Here is an simplified example to illustrate how it works:

[image]
[image]

**======Update on 15:20 22 Jun 2017======**

After I clarify with the author of this question, I'd like to deliver another approach

1. Get current product attribute set. On template file:

   ```
   $attr_set_id = $this->getProduct()->getAttributeSetId();
   ```
2. Modify create product link to `sitename.com/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/195869/s/2-pl‌​us-2-equals-to-5-mag‌​ic-mug/?attr_set_id=<?php echo $attr_set_id; ?>`
3. Modify the function `saveProduct()`. Read the attribute from URL to determine which attribute set is being used:

   ```
   public function saveProduct($type, $doSave = true, $originalProduct) 
   {
       $attr_set_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('attr_set_id');
       Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
       $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
       $product->setTypeId($type)->setAttributeSetId($attr_set_id);

       $product->save();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your time , I am extremely sorry , this is not what i needed...... we need to set the attribute set when we are trying to create product programtically once we click on button in product view page....

Comment: You can apply the same principle from me. No matter how'd you import the products, just set the `attribute_set_code` in your own format (Of course, DON'T hard code it), then you can switch across product attribute sets in ONE time.

Comment: Once we click on custom button which is present in `product page 1` [ assume `Mobile Product page` ] . we are calling `controller code` as i mentioned in question and in that controller we are using `attribute set id = 2`, in same way once we click on same custom button present in  `Product page 2` [assume  `Watch Product page` ] we are calling same controlller function , so this time also new product will create with attribute set id = 2 , but here i need to create new product with attribute set id = 4.... [ `Mobile Product` is created with `attribute set id = 1` & Watch Product page with 3 ]

Comment: So that's the point. You should NOT hard code the `->setAttributeSetId(2)`. You should make it dynamic. Either get it by URL attributes or other possible methods.

Comment: got it, if you give with code, that will be really helpfull...

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: Thanks, how i can create different url links as you suggested for both mobile and watch product page, right now for any new products we are creating with this url : `sitename.com/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/195869/s/2-plus-2-equals-to-5-magic-mug/` where `195869` is  product id & `2-plus-2-equals-to-5-magic-mug` is product name......

Comment: Added 1 more step on my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60878/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-py-yick).

Comment: For step one, this should be enough .... `$this->getProduct()->getAttributeSetId()`. No extra `load()`needed. I'd also use an event/observer, instead of modifing `save()` function. Fitting event could be `catalog_product_save_before`.

Comment: i added your 1st step code, but still its creating product with same old url..... i guess i need to attach that code to Product url code right, please tell me how i can do that ?

Comment: @sv3n Thanks for your comment, can you please help me for this question......

Answer (score 3):

Pass attribute set name to function argument

```
<div onclick="createP("original")">Original</div>
<div onclick="createP("new")">New</div>
```

Create javascript file with ajaxcall

```
<script>
    function createP(attributesetname)
    {
        //ajax Call pass parameter 
    }
</script>
```

I have created magento outer script you need to move it in controllers and update some code

```
require_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app();
Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
//$productt = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

//$attributesetname = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam(attributesetname) 
try
{

    $attributeSetCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_name' ,$attributesetname )->getFirstItem();

    echo $getattributesetidfromname = $attributeSetCollection->getAttributeSetId();
    $product->setTypeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
        ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
        ->setAttributeSetId(getattributesetidfromname) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
        ->setTypeId('simple') //product type
        ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product cr
        ->setSku('testsku61') //SKU
        ->setName('test product21') //product name
        ->setWeight(4.0000)
        ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
        ->setTaxClassId(0)
        ->setStockData(array(
                       'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                       'manage_stock'=>1, //manage stock
                       'min_sale_qty'=>1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                       'max_sale_qty'=>2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                       'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                       'qty' => 999 //qty
                   )
        )
        ->save();
        echo 'done';

}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo "in exception" .$e->getMessage();
}
//$1product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
//echo count($1product);
echo "end";
```

I have checked in my local server its working

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this didt worked for me...

Comment: Error : SQLSTATE[23000] : Integirty constraint violation : 1452 : cant add or update child row .....

Comment: Are you get attributesetcode name in function 

echo $getattributesetidfromname = $attributeSetCollection->getAttributeSetId();
die();

and test the attributeid is get or not.

Comment: seems i am not getting attribute id......

Comment: can you trace your code

$attributeSetCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')->getCollection();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($attributeSetCollection->getData());
die();

Comment: Check that the attribute set name exist in collection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60953/discussion-between-monarch1-and-baby-in-magento).

Comment: do you have any other idea ?

Comment: Yes i will do it later let me have access for trace and check